# How to integrate gitlab repo (develop branch) in sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, sonarqube

I am very new to the sonarqube.
I am running sonarqube via docker and I want to get my GitLab projects reflected there.
kindly guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to invoke `sonarscanner` from you Gitlab CI and point to your Sonarqube instance (either cloud or on-premise).

You can start with [the SonarQube manual](https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.4/analysis/gitlab-cicd/), which has a snippet of `gitlab-ci.yml` that you can drop into your pipeline.